# PHP file Upload on Windows 2008 server

Tags: php, upload, windows-server-2008

I am using this code to upload files to a windows server:

```
        // Move the file over.
        if (move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "uploads/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}")) {
```

The error log result says:
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Windows\Temp\phpF2C3.tmp' 
to 'C:\wwwroot\uploads/flag.png' in C:\CustomerData\webspaces\webspace_00254529\wwwroot\upload_image.php on line 35

I assume this is a path related error (the folders have full permissions) but I am unsure how to include the path code into the upload file.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: I remember seeing something similar to your question last week. I believe what was needed to be done was to use `/` in front of the upload folder. Thus, `"/uploads/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}"` give that a try. Plus permissions could also be a factor.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, also with back slash but no luck

Comment: Sometimes the error doesn't necessarily originate from the given/said line. Many or most of the times it's because of the line above it. What's on the line above line 35?

Comment: By the way, does the `uploads` folder exist?

Comment: Yes the "uploads" folder exists with read/write permissions.

Comment: The lines above:if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

 // Check for an uploaded file:
 if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
  
  // Validate the type. Should be JPEG or PNG.
  $allowed = array ('application/pdf', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X-PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/png', 'image/x-png',);
  if (in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $allowed)) {

Comment: Are you using `$dest = "c:\\program files\\folder group\\apache2\\htdocs\\uploads\\";` as an example for a destination folder?

Comment: Plus, usual arrays I seen is something to the affect of `$allowed = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png');` which script are you using, or did you write it yourself?

Comment: I am trying to upload to a hosted windows 2008 server,. It all works fine on Linux/Apaches

Comment: I found this, not sure if will help though http://www.howyoudo.info/index.php/how-to-fix-windows-server-upload-file-inherit-permissions-error/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721285/php-file-uploading-issues / http://stackoverflow.com/a/15726984/1415724

Comment: Try adding this as your first line of code `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, there may be some important information you can get from it. Plus, do a `var_dump($upload);`

Comment: Have a look at one of my answers and tell me if your code looks similar, in ways of folder destination, filename from form input etc. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16995198/1415724

Comment: This seems to be relevant but not sure how to do OK, the answer was simple. I was adding permissions for user: IIS_USRS, when it should have been just user: USRS.it?

Comment: That I don't know. I work with Linux servers (hosted) and don't have my own Web server. So my guess would be to go under **"Windows/users"** type of thing. I don't know how else to help you.